# Calling Keras LSTM by class

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm a Java developer and still new to Python and Keras. I have a working example with this code:

```
encoder_lstm = LSTM(self.latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_inputs)
```

So I understand that the first line I am creating an object of class `LSTM`, but then I'm passing an `ndarray` (or similar) to this object, but not specifying any function to call.

How can I tell what function is being called here? I'm guessing I need to look at `def call` but is `call` a "default" function for Python or Keras?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a class in Python, you can define a `__call__` method for that class. This way the instantiated objects of that class behave as a function upon a call:

```
class MyClass():
   # ...
   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       print("The object was called!")

>>> obj = MyClass()
>>> obj()
"The object was called!"
```

Now if you take a look at the source code of Keras, you would find that the base layer class (i.e. [`Layer`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/8461b0920a61a50d83fd147bb4e8c16c4e9126ff/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L22)), which all the layers in Keras inherit from this class, has a [`__call__`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/8461b0920a61a50d83fd147bb4e8c16c4e9126ff/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L382) method:

```
def __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs):
    """Wrapper around self.call(), for handling internal references.
```

This method do some checks on the inputs and update internal references and then calls the `call` method of the layer. That's why when [implementing a custom layer in Keras](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) you just need to override its `call` method (rather than `__call__`) which is specific to Keras.

Now when you create a layer in Keras like this:

```
encoder_lstm = LSTM(self.latent_dim, return_state=True)
```

and then call it in on **input tensor(s)** (not numpy arrays) like this:

```
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_inputs)
```

essentially first the `__call__` method of base layer is called, which internally calls the `call` method of the corresponding layer, which in this example is the `LSTM` layer. And the `call` method is where all the logic (i.e. computation logic) of the layer resides.

Answer (score 2):

Some objects in Python are "callable".

There is indeed a standard method implemented for callable objects, but it's not the `call` you see in Keras code. It's a `__call__` method. (Python uses this notation with two underscores before and after for such standard methods, like `__init__` which is the constructor method)

In Keras, you will only find the `__call__` method in the **base_layer**: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py/#L382

Internally, this method will end up calling the `call` (not a Python standard, but required for all Keras layers) method in derived layers. So, in case you're looking into Keras's code for LSTM, or you're creating a custom layer, it's enough to look at the `call` method. It contains the tensor operations necessary to understand the network's math without all the overhead.